# Bokeh plot categorial ticks on numerical axis?

Tags: plot, label, bokeh, axis, categorical-data

I have [this bokeh plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EIaV.jpg) where the ticks at the moment indicate the startposition of a new chromosome with a total of five chromsomes (so on the x-axis at position 37, the third chromsome starts and ends at 53, sampe principle for the y-axis).

I would like to add extra (minor?) categorial ticks inbetween those coordinates so it will be more clearly, a little bit like the [nested categories hvar example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#nested-categories) from the bokeh website, but instead of fruits you have the chromosome names.

I have this `DFtotal` (sorted on `value`) as input:

```
      xmar     xname   ygen      yname     value
3368    46  c3_10996  13201  AT3G27420  3.000099
2583    36  c2_18753   9491  AT2G40440  3.000142
2650    37  c3_00580  10335  AT2G16360  3.000501
3946    57  c4_03833  16262  AT4G02830  3.000592
914     12  c1_18433  14488  AT3G55120  3.001359
```

And this is the `chDF` with chromosome data:

```
chname  Ymiddle Xmiddle  Ystart  Xstart
ch1      4461.5    11.0       0       0
ch2     11572.0    29.5    8924      23
ch3     17703.5    45.0   14221      37
ch4     23715.5    61.5   21187      54
ch5     30070.5    79.0   26245      70
```

My code for the plotting at the moment is as following:

```
#Add tools to plot
TOOLS= "hover, pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,box_zoom,undo,redo,reset,save"

#Create empty figure
p = figure(tools=TOOLS)


#----- ADD CATEGORIAL TICKS IN THIS PART -----#
mtick = list(chDF.Xstart)
gtick = list(chDF.Ystart)

p.xaxis[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks = mtick)
p.xgrid[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks = mtick) 
p.yaxis[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks = gtick)  
p.ygrid[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks = gtick)

#---------------------------------------------#

#Create CDS
SOURCE = ColumnDataSource(DFtotal)

#Create palette
LCM = LinearColorMapper( palette=list(reversed(np.array(Reds9))), low = 
min(DFtotal['value']),
                     high = max(DFtotal['value']) )

#Create plot
p.circle(x='xmar', y='ygen', source=SOURCE, fill_color={'field':'value', 
'transform':LCM},
     line_color={'field':'value', 'transform':LCM}, size=6, fill_alpha=0.8)

#show
output_file("test.html", title="test")
show(p)
```

I have literally no clue how to tackle this problem

Comment: Hi again, I don't know how to do this either unfortunately. You could: draw a line glyph between 0 and 23 and annotate it with "Chromosome 1"  etc for the other chromosomes. Then you have the chromosome map in your plot. You can also add a second axis like at the bottom of this page of the user manual: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html

Comment: Do you know how I can annotate this, so "Chromosome 1" is annotated to 11,5 for example?